# Select first record in group where no overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of rows which looks like this, ordered by First_Date

```
Id         First_Date   Second_Date
ABC12345   2022-05-18   2022-08-16
ABC12345   2022-05-23   2022-08-29
ABC12345   2022-06-06   2022-11-23
ABC12345   2022-06-16   2022-11-23
ABC12345   2022-08-16   2022-11-23
ABC12345   2022-11-01   2022-11-29
```

After always keeping the first rows, I want to include all following rows where the first_date does not fall between (exclusive) the two dates in this first record.

Once there is a row which is not excluded (example above would be fifth record), then it would check the next row against this until the end.

So I only want to keep dates where there is no overlap at all - same dates are OK, just not between.

So I want the final result to look like this

```
Id         First_Date   Second_Date   Flag
ABC12345   2022-05-18   2022-08-16    Keep
ABC12345   2022-05-23   2022-08-29    Exclude
ABC12345   2022-06-06   2022-11-23    Exclude
ABC12345   2022-06-16   2022-11-23    Exclude
ABC12345   2022-08-16   2022-11-23    Keep
ABC12345   2022-11-01   2022-11-29    Exclude
```

Is there any way of doing this. I've tried LAG function, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Your description and your expected results don't seem to match. You state you want to **exclude** rows where the first date doesn't fall within the dates of the first row. Why, therefore, is `2022-05-23` excluded when it *is* between `2022-05-18` and `2022-08-16`? Based on your description, the only row to be excluded would be the one with a first date of `2022-11-01`.

Comment: "first" and "following" -- For ordering purposes, are you sorting the rows by (id, first_date)?

Comment: Because of the ripple effect, this will require an iterative solution, but this might be possible in a single statement that encapsulates the iteration in a recursive CTE that chains the kept records.  I've done similar in the past (Working on it.)

Comment: Apologies, had it the wrong way around. I want to include dates which do not fall between the two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that if multiple Id values are present, each should be handled separately.

The following will use several Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to (1) Define a well-defined row ordering, (2) Define a relationship between each row and the first eligible "following" row, and finally (3) Chain the linked rows together using a recursive CTE that starts with the first row for each Id (RowNum = 1) and follows the chain of linked rows.

Following that, you can either select the chained rows directly to get the filtered data, or join them back to the original data to generate the Keep/Exclude flag as you posted in your requested results.

```
;WITH OrderedData AS (
    SELECT
        D.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY D.Id
            ORDER BY D.First_Date, D.Second_Date DESC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM Data D
),
LinkedData AS (
    SELECT D.*, D2.RowNum AS NextRowNum
    FROM OrderedData D
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 D2.*
        FROM OrderedData D2
        WHERE D2.Id = D.Id
        AND D2.RowNum > D.RowNum
        AND D2.First_Date >= D.Second_Date
        ORDER BY D2.RowNum
    ) D2
), ChainedData AS (
    SELECT LD.*
    FROM LinkedData LD
    WHERE LD.RowNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LD.*
    FROM ChainedData CD
    JOIN LinkedData LD
        ON LD.Id = CD.Id
        AND LD.RowNum = CD.NextRowNum
)
SELECT
    D.*,
    CASE WHEN CD.RowNum IS NOT NULL THEN 'Keep' ELSE 'Exclude' END AS Flag
FROM OrderedData D
LEFT JOIN ChainedData CD
        ON CD.Id = D.Id
        AND CD.RowNum = D.RowNum
ORDER BY D.Id, D.RowNum
```

The OrderedData step might be skipped if you have no duplicate First_Date for a given Id. In that case, you could replace most occurrences or RowNum with First_Date. If there can be duplicate First_Date values, the next question is which record to chose - the one with the earliest Second_Date or the latest?

For efficiency you should probably place an index on Data(Id, First_Date) at a minimum.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rsMokfoB) for a working demo with additional test data.

Sample results:

| Id | First_Date | Second_Date | RowNum | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC12345 | 2022-05-18 | 2022-08-16 | 1 | Keep |
| ABC12345 | 2022-05-23 | 2022-08-29 | 2 | Exclude |
| ABC12345 | 2022-06-06 | 2022-11-23 | 3 | Exclude |
| ABC12345 | 2022-06-16 | 2022-11-23 | 4 | Exclude |
| ABC12345 | 2022-08-16 | 2022-11-23 | 5 | Keep |
| ABC12345 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-29 | 6 | Exclude |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | Keep |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-05 | 2 | Keep |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-06 | 3 | Exclude |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-07 | 4 | Exclude |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-08 | 5 | Keep |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-20 | 6 | Keep |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-25 | 7 | Exclude |
| DEF00001 | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-31 | 8 | Keep |

Comment: @Jameel - Critical fix - I mistakenly omitted a critical `ORDER BY D2.RowNum` from the `CROSS APPLY (...)` in my original post. This is now corrected above and in the fiddle. Without the ORDER BY, results may be correct for small data sets, but may become unstable when large data sets (aka "production data") are involved.